# Sql Server Compare 1 Result Set against Another to return matches are fields that are not null

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to compare 2 result sets?
For instance, the main table looks like this:

```
Record  DepartmentId     PositionId   EmployeeId  StatusId
  1        Null            Null         Null        4
  2         7               454         Null        Null
  3         Null            454         Null        3
```

I want to return the record numbers that match this:

```
DepartmentId PositionId EmployeeId StatusId
     7         454         545        4
```

In this scenario, it would return Record 1 (because it matches the StatusId), Record 2 (because it matches both the DepartmentId and the PositionId), but it would not return Record 3 because it only matches the PositionId and not the StatusId.

I have been trying to figure out how to write a Query to do this but I cannot figure out how to handle the "AND"s per record and when some fields on the main table are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE COAELSCE(DepartmentId,7)=7
  AND COAELSCE(PositionId,454)=454
  AND COAELSCE(EmployeeId,545)=545
  AND COAELSCE(StatusId,4) IN (4,5,6)
```

It will replace each of the given columns with the second value in the `COALESCE()` function if it was found to be `null` and then it will be compared to the value after the `=`.

See the demo here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1404359

**Edit**
To allow multiple values for `StatusId` simply change the `=4` to `IN (4,5,6)` or to whatever values you want to allow.

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly on my small sample table but It does not work on my large actual result set and I just can't figure out why.  The only difference I can see is that to produce the main table there are several joins.  I am trying to insert the result set into a table now to see if that matters.

Comment: It is of course important that none of the values to be compared _with_ is `null`.

Comment: I see why.  If all of the fields on the main table are NULL, it returns them as well, and it should not.

Comment: this should work if I continue building the Coalesce statements for each field because there will never be a time when ALL fields are null.  The problem is when I get to multi values.  The second table can have multiple values for the CustomerId and TeamId fields .  is there any way to use "IN" with the Coalesce?

Comment: @user15810458 What does `multiple values` mean: is it multiple rows or a comma separated list (which you really shouldn't use)?

Comment: "which you really shouldn't use" - sounds almost like an urban myth. :D - There is nothing wrong with an `IN (...)` list if it only has a handful of elements in it.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann I was referring to `IN (@myCSV)` which obviously doesn't work and requires string-splitting.