# SQL Check to see if any value in a list exists in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table that looks something like this:

```
Record  DepartmentId     PositionId   EmployeeId  StatusId    CustomerId
  1        Null            Null         Null        4  
  2         7              454          Null        Null
  3        Null            454          Null        3
  3        Null            Null         Null        Null        214
  3        Null            Null         Null        Null        100
  3        Null            Null         Null        Null        312
  4        Null            Null         Null        Null        357
```

I inserted the above into the temp table from tables that looked like this:

```
Record Table      Record-to-Department      Record-to-Position
Record  Name       Record   DepartmentId    Record    PositionId
1       Red          2          7             2          454
2       blue                                  3          454
3       Green
4       Purple

Record-To-Status             Record-To-Customer
Record    StatusId           Record    CustomerId
1         4                    3          214
3         3                    3          100
                               3          312
                               4          357
```

I have an employee whose record looks something like this:

```
   EmployeeId DepartmentId   PositionId   StatusId
       342         7           454           4

Employee Customers:
EmployeeId   CustomerId
 342             357
 342             95
 342             720
```

In this scenario, it would return Record 1 (because it matches the StatusId), Record 2 (because it matches both the DepartmentId and the PositionId), but it would not return Record 3 because it only matches the PositionId and not the StatusId, and it would return RecordId 4 because one of the Employee CustomerIds matches the CustomerId on Record 4.

I got part of this answer on another question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372582/sql-server-compare-1-result-set-against-another-to-return-matches-are-fields-tha) (please forgive me I am new and trying to figure out how to ask everything I need to know), but I can't figure out how to handle the multi-records.

I tried selecting the Employees customer Id's into a table variable and then attempted to use the Coalesce like this:

```
Declare @Customers table(CustomerId int)
INSERT INTO @Customers(CustomerId)
SELECT DISTINCT S.CustomerId 
FROM employee_Customers


Select * from tbl
WHERE
COAlesce(StatusId,@StatusId)=@StatusId AND
COALESCE(DepartmentId,@DepartmentId)=@DepartmentId AND
Coalesce(PositionId,@PositionId)=@PositionId AND
Coalesce(EmployeeCompanyId,@EmployeeCompanyId) = @EmployeeCompanyId AND
COALESCE((Select CustomerId from tbl_Requirement_to_Customer),(Select CustomerId from @Customers)) = (Select CustomerId from @Customers)
```

But I receive the error "Subquery Returned more than 1 value".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Should the ID record 3 not be unique rather than repeated 4 times? Also, your data has missing values under customer ID. And where is the relationship between employee and customer help. I think you may need to sort out your data structures before moving on.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!  No to your question, it is repeated because it forms a unique key with the CustomerId on that table.

Comment: See my other comments. What is `record` and why is it repeated?

Comment: The two `COALESCE` statements in your last line are generating the error.

Comment: The values in this table where inserted from a Main table and several junction tables.  The Record table has a Record-to-department table, a Record-to-Status table, a Record-to-position table, etc. I inserted them into a temp table in order to try to create the query that I need.  It may not have been the best way to do it, but I was having a harder time with all of the junction tables.

Comment: @PeterSmith - I added the breakdown with the junction tables in case that is better than inserting everything into the temp table.

Comment: Struggling to make sense of your logic. Why is record 3 invalid, it doesn't match StatusId but neither does record 2; is there a rule that two values must match? But then record 4 doesn't match StatusId and only has 1 match on the CustomerId, so that doesn't work. Can you clearly state what the rules for matching are.

Comment: Yes.  if a record has more than one value on a row  they must match.  So if you are in Position 454 AND Status 3 or Any of those customerIds, then Record 3 would be in the result set. Across is ANDS, down is ORs, if that helps to make any more sense.

Comment: @Stu did my explanation make any further sense? This is my first job.  I just finished school.  If the experts on here can't figure this out, I don't know how I am supposed to.  I do appreciate everyone who  has/is trying to help.

Comment: @user15810458 I believe so, I am having a play around with an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a possible solution you can try. I don't think it will be plug-and-play but hopefully you can adapt it to your situation. I am using just the data as presented in your temp table, your `employee` record and your `Employee-customers` correlation.

The basic logic is to join your temp table to the employee(s) using `or` condition, but then to get a count of populated values, and compare this count to a count of the number of matching values, which must be at least the first count and greater than zero.

This returns your desired output:

```
select t.*
from Temp t
left join emp e on e.DepartmentId=t.DepartmentId or e.PositionId=t.PositionId or e.EmployeeId=t.EmployeeId or e.StatusId=t.StatusId
outer apply (
    select case when exists (
        select * from EmployeeCustomers ec join emp e on e.EmployeeId=ec.EmployeeId where ec.CustomerID=t.CustomerId
    ) then 1 else 0 end CustomerIdMatch
)c
outer apply (
    values ( 
        Iif(t.departmentId is null,0,1) + 
        Iif(t.PositionId is null,0,1) +
        Iif(t.EmployeeId is null,0,1) +
        Iif(t.StatusId is null,0,1) +
        c.CustomerIdMatch
))x(Cnt)
outer apply (
    values ( 
        Iif(t.departmentId=e.DepartmentId,1,0) + 
        Iif(t.PositionId=e.PositionId,1,0) +
        Iif(t.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId,1,0) +
        Iif(t.StatusId=e.StatusId,1,0) +
        c.CustomerIdMatch
))y(Cnt2)
where cnt2>=cnt and cnt2>0
```

See working [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4ddb5f8ba41ea71b028529e24c3ddd5)

Comment: There are no words to thank you for this!  I would have NEVER figured this out.  I am totally unfamiliar with "outer apply" and will have to do a little research to really understand what you did here so I can reproduce it if needed in the future.